# Solution needed for first order ODE

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

$\frac{dy}{dx}$$= \frac{(x+3y-5)}{(x-y-1)}$
The equation is neither homogeneous nor linear. It's not variable separable either.

Comment: are you sure that you have made no typo?

Comment: [![graph][1]][1]

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/y0a24.jpg   @Mahalashmi Mohan To guess next step, I included a graph. It has a max, a min, an asymptote

Answer (score 4):

Substitute $x = t+2$, $y= u+1$, and it becomes $$u' = \dfrac{t+3u}{t-u}$$
which is homogeneous.

BTW, Maple gives the solution as

$$y \left( x \right) =1-{\frac { \left( x-2 \right)  \left( {\rm W} 
\left(2\,c \left( x-2 \right) \right)+2 \right) }{{\rm W} \left(2\,c
 \left( x-2 \right) \right)}}
$$
where $W$ is the Lambert W function.

Comment: Tried to check how Lambert comes in here                     $$ \frac{dy}{dx}= \frac {ax+by + ..}{Ax+By+ ..} $$

By substitution $ x = t+ p;\, y= u+q; $ and choosing $(p,q) $ constants evaluated as 

$$ p=(b C - B c)/D ; q=(A c - a C)/D; D = (a B- A b); $$

with further homogenizing substitution  $ u= v \,t $

I obtained, 

$$ -\frac{dt}{t}= \frac{(A+B v) dv}{( B v^2+ (A-b) v-a)} $$                                                             Is that correct?

Comment: first line skould be $\dfrac{dy}{dx}= \dfrac{ax+by+c}{Ax+By+C}$